# IntelliJ not working with Java?

Tags: compiler-construction, sdk, compiler-errors, intellij-idea, java

Recently, I downloaded and installed IntelliJ to try it out. It seems like a nice interface, and I really want to try it out, but it doesn't seem to be working with my JDK. I gave it the following code:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Hello World. ");
  }
}
```

To my surprise, when I compiled it, I got this error:

> java: Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

I checked online for more help, and many things said to check:

> "File" -> "Project Structure" -> "Platform Settings" -> "SDK"

And then add your JDK (JDK 1.7). That didn't work, so I tried JDK 1.6, which also gave me the same error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What OS do you use? Can you attach the screenshot with the JSDK classpath configuration?